# Getting an error syntax error near unexpected token `then'

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

```
check: default
        ./lab0 --ip \
        if [[ $$? -eq 1 ]];  then \
         echo "incorrect argument recognised"; \
        fi
```

Hi i am writing bash script in my make file and running a C program but I am getting error Getting an error syntax error near unexpected token `then' . I believe spacing is right.

Comment: Please run your code thru http://shellcheck.net . If that solves your problem, then please delete this Q as it will not easily help other users. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Can we test **makefiles** with shellcheck.net????

Comment: @user1934428 : I was referring to the shell code included in the makefile. As @lover below indicates, a missing `;` would have been flagged. Interestingly, the missing semicolon is not apparent in the edit history. Oh well ? Good luck to all.

Answer (score 3):

You need a semicolon (`;`) after the first command before the backslash. Without the semicolon, `if` is just interpreted as the next argument to the command `./lab0`, while `then` after the existing semicolon is interpreted as a keyword (which must come after an `if` keyword, hence the syntax error).

BTW you could simplify this command using the `||` operator instead of `if`:

```
./lab0 --ip || echo "incorrect argument recognised"
```

Comment: To be clear, you need the semicolon _in addition to_ the backslash, not instead of.  Without the backslash `make` will run each line in a separate shell which is not what the question wants to do.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it. When I originally constructed the answer, the question was differently formatted, so command boundaries were at different places.